# SP13: Alert Me - Setup Email

Tags: 2013, workflow, document-library, alert

I am not sure if this has already been addressed before.  When setting up Alerts using "Alert Me" within a document library an notification email is sent to the any persons added to the "Send Alerts To" field.  The email lets the person know that an alert has been set-up...etc. Since a lot of alerts are created the notification emails tend to crowd my inbox. So, it's not the "actual" alert email for the changes to the document library, but rather the setup email notifications that are crowding my inbox.

Is there a way not receive the Alert Me **set-up** notification email when alert is designated to be sent to me?  Thanks!

Comment: why not write a outlook rule to delete these messages? thats an option right?

Comment: Maybe it can help to empty the Email template?

Comment: @Anand Thanks for your suggestion.  I am not sure if it's an option, but I will try.

Comment: @Sascha Thank you for your comment.  If I empty the email template, what would that do? I believe the email is self-generated in SharePoint. Would I still empty the template? Thanks again for your help.